# Swift 5 Save AVAsset to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults, avasset

Users can scroll through the feed and retrieve videos from my cloud storage.
I would like to cache the videos (which I do successfully temporary in an array) but I want to retrieve the videos also when restarting the App.
Currently, if the user kills the app and starts again the temporary folder is of course empty.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: use CoreData and store it there. keep a boolean value to identify it is locally stored or not , if it is locally stored just retrieve it and play it. you can store videos and photos as Data in CoreData. for videos and photos please don't use Userdefaults by the way, it is a small memory space better you use CoreData

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will take a look!

Comment: can't you give a upvote if you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the assets. There are several technologies for this, such as files in the user directory, CoreData, SQLite, etc. UserDefaults would not be recommended for such large files.